# Trouble with routing in django - page not found

Tags: django

I am not able to perform routing.

error at /home:
[enter image description here]

```
urls.py:
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from app.views import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('home/', views.home_view, name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_view(*args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World<h1>")
```

Comment: Never seen it done like this, but try to change your urls.py like this: `from app.views import views`, then in your urlpatterns do `path('home/', views.home_view, name='home')`.  Also, please no *images* of code; it makes it tough to troubleshoot.  Good luck.

Comment: Please post your code instead of prints. Said that your problem seems that django doesn't loaded your code changes, try to kill server and start it again, if persist try to delete your ```path('home'...)``` save and write again

Comment: it does not work. Why did you never seen it done like this? Should I change my code somehow?

Comment: @Małgorzata Please post your code instead of images

Comment: View functions I've always seen like this: `def home_view(request):` .  I just meant *I* never saw a view function like this.  I really don't know if that's the problem.

Comment: And the import statement should be as @Razenstein stated, `from app import views` not as I stated initially.

Answer (score 0):

From the limited information (at the time of writing this answer) provided by OP, it seems the django app `app` is not registered in `INSTALLED_APPS`

From the images, it seems the project is structured like this

```
project/
├── app
│   ├── __init__py
│   └── views.py
├── asgi.py
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── settings.py
├── urls.py
└── wsgi.py
```

You need to add `app` in the `INSTALLED_APPS` list in your `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'app',
...
]
```

This activates your sub-app `app` to be used in your django project.

Comment: The original [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0cmT.png) was a path not found error, I think not having the app in INSTALLED_APPS would cause a different error.

Comment: it is installed, sorry to not mention that

Answer (score 0):

the import in urls.py should be

```
from app import views
```

but it is difficult to judge without the full error message

Comment: full error message:Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/home
Using the URLconf defined in store.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
The current path, home, didn’t match any of these.

You’re seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.

Comment: that means your store.url is the base url of the app. That store.url is not the one that you posted in your original post above! There is only one single path "admin/" in as in the error message. btw I would recommend to add the error message to the post ass it is better readabel then in the comments

Comment: Yes, you are correct, the import statement should be as you describe, not as I wrote initially.